# Matlab GUIDE uitable remove NaN values

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am reading a excel file and displaying it in uitable in Matlab GUIDE.

Code for reading file and displaying to uitable is

```
 [num, txt, raw] =  xlsread('D://qq.xls','D1');
 set(handles.uitable1,'visible','on','Data',raw);
```

Now my file contains all mix data, so I preferred using **raw**.

After using raw, I am getting all data but also I am getting additional **NaN** values.I am attaching screenshot
[image]
bottom part of image contains all NaN values.

I have got 2 queries:

1. How can I replace them with blank values?
2. Also, how can I replace 1 with Yes and 0 with No?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s=size(raw);
for i=1:s(1,1)
    for j=1:s(1,2)
        if strcmp(raw(i,j),'NaN')
            raw(i,j)={' '};
        end
        if isequal(raw(i,j),{1})
           raw(i,j)={'Yes'};
        end

        if isequal(raw(i,j),{0})
           raw(i,j)={'No'};
        end
    end
end
```